# Terran vs Terran - Breaking Siege Line Efficently

Tags: starcraft-2

What is the best technique for T v T when both are massing siege tanks and slowly creeping into the middle? Everything I have previously read mentioned that it is best to either go Battlecruiser or try to catch the siege tanks while they are mobile?

Is it possible to try to rush it first with Marauders (too take most of the damage) followed by Marines?  Or is the Battlecruiser the best scenario to break siege lines.

Comment: the problem with turtle it is the reaction speed, attack multiple sites at same time !!!, well I do that as zerg xD

Comment: Yeah, I know how to handle it as Zerg.  It's just a lot more annoying as a Terran going against it because you don't have the speed to attack from multiple fronts or to drop free units (infested terrans) to help break the barriers.

Comment: Try Banshees. Give them cloak if need be.

Comment: I've always found air difficult to do. Typically I have seen either Marines backing the tanks, or the Terran has a flux of minerals and will just dump missile turrets everywhere (which is quite cost effective against BCs and Banshees).  It's kind of a catch 22 at times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: **Wings of Liberty answer only, this is outdated in HotS!**

The most used tactic when you go bio vs his siege tank push is to flank his siege tanks with stimmed marauders, stutter stepping towards their dead zone as fast as possible while still shooting.

You want to apply pressure from the front at the same time to force his marines in a defensive position *in front* of the tanks, otherwise they'll just kill your marauders off.

If however you went mech, simply having your siege tanks sieged up will zone his siege tank push enough to force him to make the first move, thus taking more damage. He'll most likely try to flank *you*, so be prepared to deal with it somehow. You'll want to mass enough vikings to zone his medivacs (denying his vision) and provide vision for your tanks instead, and to expand behind your siege tank line to get enough resources for a skyterran transition (battlecruisers with raven and viking support).

Comment: Theres no 100% right answer here, in some form or another everyone is right, but I like your solution the best.  I've always been a counter type of person.  Thank you, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Another tactics that was not mentioned is : fill a medivac dropship with marines and drop them right on top of the siege tank. Of course you cannot do this safely if the opponent has air control or has a lot a marines near his siege tank but i have seen it work in pro games so it should be possible for us to pull it too. This will sacrifice some marines but will also make the other tanks kill their own tanks.

Comment: I've actually used that tactic before.  Dropping a marine or two on tanks.  It's just typically by the time someone pulls out battlecruisers, there are turrets everywhere around the tanks and its hard to break through both tanks and turrets.

Answer (score 1):

Using ravens has always worked for me.  Dropped Auto-Turrets near their tanks to cause splash damage death or to atleast soften them up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following tactics:

- Surround the siege tanks with MMM and attack all at once (similar to Zerg). Because of the huge concave only a few units of you will die.
- Scan regularly and try to catch his tanks while unsieged.
- Create some Ghosts and some Nukes and position your Ghost so he cannot kill him with his sieged tanks. Basically only the border of your Nuke should overlap with some of his tanks. Once he unsieges just cancel the Nuke with ESC and stim right into his tanks.
- Create about as much Tanks as he has and add a bunch of Vikings. Try to get Air superiority and kill his Medivacs. Now position your Vikings between his and your Tanks and wait. After a while leap a few tanks into fire range. He cannot attack you because he lacks the vision. Once your Tanks are sieged you can attack him because of your Vikings.
- Get Vikings and either Banshees or Battlecruisers with some tanks. position your air units between your hand his tanks and kill them. If he unsieges chase him. If he attacks your air units with Marines, just pull back into your tanks.
- Build some Thors and attack with your Thors at the front, MMM should follow.
- Get some tanks with MMM and siege up right next to him. Wait a while and then load up all your Medivacs to doom drop right into a vulnerable position like his base. He will loose a lot of his units if he tries push, because of your tanks. Once he backs off, load your units into the Medivacs and retreat or attack another position.
- Get more expansions than he has and build more production facilities and just wait. He has to attack eventually. If he destroys your army just create a new one before he reaches your base.

If you like MMM I would suggest using Ghosts, but it takes a while to get your first Nuke ready.

If you are a beginner, then I would suggest going Tank, Viking with a few Banshees.

Answer (score 1):

One technique I've seen used for softening them before the main attack is to do a scan of the siege line and then drop MULE on top of a few of them. The splash damage can significantly damage or even destroy a few before you get there.

Note that this is typically used in the late game, when you have a number of command centers with excess energy available.

Comment: Love the thought.  I've actually done it before and was told it is BM.  Mules can go anywhere literally, and I've used them to soften up defenses before.  If you are going to hunker that much than why not drop mules :)  +1